# Sql select distinct group 2 columns

Tags: sql, distinct

My table is:

```
title   type
a       category
b       category
d       tag
a       category
c       tag
r       tag
t       category 
d       category
```

I am trying to select unique values for each (category and tag)

How would I merge these 2 queries?

```
SELECT DISTINCT title, type FROM table WHERE type='category'

SELECT DISTINCT title, type FROM table WHERE type='tag'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this would seem to do what you want:

```
select distinct title, type
from table
where type in ('category', 'tag')
order by type;
```

I added the order by so the `type`s are all together.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with "group by" which find the unique combinations

```
select title, type
from table
group by title, type;
```